# Finding probability of sets

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to find the probability of certain sets. Here's the task at hand:

> If P(A) = 0.4, P(B) = 0.5, and P(A $\cap$ B) = 0.3, find **(a)** P(A
>   $\cup$ B), **(b)** P(A $\cap$ B') and **(c)** P(A' $\cup$ B')

Here's what I have so far:

**a.]** P(A) + P(B) - P(A $\cap$ B) = 0.4 + 0.5 - 0.3

=0.6

**b.]** P(A) - P(A $\cap$ B) = 0.4 -0.3

= 0.1

**c.]** 0

Am I correct in what I have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(a) and (b) are correct.

As regards (c), we have that $(A'\cup B')'=A\cap B$, hence
$$P(A'\cup B')=1-P((A'\cup B')')=1-P(A\cap B)=1-0.3=0.7.$$